# How to get yes or no if a specific format is true or false in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please suggest me a formula to derive this result,

I want to check whether all cells in a column is in the below format and return Yes if it s true and No if it is not true.

Text format: gsfddyf - sdfgff - jhfgeufg

Example,

ETA - Susan - ETA login issues => Yes

ETA : Susan : ETA login issues (or) any othe formats other than "-" or with out any seperations => No

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how deeply you want to check, then this might work:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," - ",""))=6,"yes","no")
```

[image]